# Solve $ 3 f(x) = 3 + \int_1^x {f^3(t)+t \over f^2(t)} \,dt \, , x\ge 1 $

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to solve

$$ 3 f(x) = 3 + \int_1^x {f^3(t)+t \over f^2(t)} \,dt \, , x\ge 1 $$

We see that $ f(1) = 1 $. If we differentiate both sides we get

$$ 3 f'(x) = {f^3(x)+x \over f^2(x)} $$

This simplifies to

$$ f'(x) = {f(x) \over 3} + {x \over 3f^2(x)} $$

If I multiply both sides by $ f^2(x) $ I get an equation I either haven't seen before, or maybe I've just forgotten. Anyhow, this is as far as I've gotten (not very far admittedly).

Comment: if you put x=1 so 3f(1)=3+0 --->f(1)=1 for initial condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you multiply by $3f^2$ you get to $$3f'(x)(f(x))^2 = (f(x))^3+x$$ making the substitution $g(x) = (f(x))^3$ we find $g'(x) = 3f'(x)(f(x))^2$. This changes the differential equation to $g'(x) = g(x) + x$.

Continuing, rewrite this as $g'(x)-g(x) = x$ then multiply both sides by $e^{-x}$ which leads to $$g'(x)e^{-x}-e^{-x}g(x)=(g(x)e^{-x})' = xe^{-x}$$ and finally we have $$e^{-x}g(x)-e^{-1}g(1) = \int_{1}^x te^{-t}dt.$$ You can finish by integration by parts on the right.

Comment: Well, you won't be quite done - you still need to use the initial condition $f(1)$

Comment: That's true. But the OP can wrap that up. :)

Comment: Though I guess we should use the $g(1)$ instead of $g(0)$ as well as changing the integral to $\int_1^x$, but the ideas are the same.

Comment: Thanks Joel. That was kind of a tricky problem. I'm glad I asked because I don't think I'd ever figure it out by myself.

Comment: I am glad that I could help. It's always fun when you see a complicated DE that turns out to be not so bad after a substitution.